# Как сделать волну на фоне?

Tags: css

у меня есть страница с карточками, на фоне расположена "волна", вроде выглядит супер просто, но не могу понять как сделать ее просто и правильно, подскажите пожалуйста!
У меня есть svg с этой волной, но опять же как разбить весь фон на две части, чтобы не затронуть контент весь, что-то совсем туплю(((

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE**
[Вот svg волны](https://dropmefiles.com/uiq0q)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нашел SVG с повторяющейся волной поэтому такой не аккуратный переход, но с Вашим SVG должно работать. Просто подставьте путь к своему файлу в `background-image: url( путь )`

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxNjgwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjE5NiI+PHBhdGggZmlsbD0iI0ZGRiIgZD0iTS03NCA4Ny4zMDdDMTQ1LjM5MyAyOS4xMDIgMzQ5LjYyNyAwIDUzOC43MDIgMGMyODMuNjExIDAgNTAyLjIyNyA2My4yMzUgNzg0LjcyNCA4Ny4zMDcgMTg4LjMzMiAxNi4wNDggMzMyLjE5IDEuNDk3IDQzMS41NzQtNDMuNjUzVjE5NkgtNzRWODcuMzA3eiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: auto 50%;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  background-position: bottom;
}

.content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример!
У меня правда свг белой волны... и вот у меня в этом проблема, получается, что после волны нет сплошного белого фона.
Но я понял принцип, думал в этом направлении тоже. Буду пробовать или же найду другой исходник волны просто.

Как закончу с примером отпишусь

Comment: Можете приложить свой SVG к вопросу, тогда я смогу помочь

Comment: Добавил ссылку на скачивание svg, если вы подскажите как с этой свг сделать такой же вариант, то будет супер))

Comment: @nazarukroman Готово, если захотите поиграть с размерами ширина/высота волны, то меняйте `background-size`. Первый параметр **width**, второй **height**

Comment: Спасибо за пример еще раз! Но к сожалению, когда масштабирую свг волны, то идет отличие от макета, но это уже скорее дело в графике. Сделал немного подругому